# "Add Reference" options is not available in Class Library project dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-client-profile

I am building a webAPI client project called "eCommUtility.Client", and I am trying to add a reference to the "System.Web.dll" to use `HttpContext`. However, whenever I try to add a new reference, the options I get are only "add a project reference" or "add a service reference". The Project is a `.Net Class Library.`

Here is what is provided when right-clicking the dependencies:

[image]

Ande here are the options provided when right-clicking the project and going to the `add` option:
[image]

Here are the project properties:
[image]

I am not sure if I can enable it somehow? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't reference arbitrary assemblies from a .NET Standard Class Library. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: To use HttpContext

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Rather, why do you want to reference legacy ASP.NET in a .NET Standard Class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created your project, you selected .Net Standard 2.0, not .Net Framework... They are not the same. "Add reference" is a menu you get on a .net framework project, not .net standard.